# How can I set up conditional code reviews in BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request

I am working in a team using Bit Bucket and the PR code review process. I was wondering if it is possible to have conditional approval.

I know it's possible to set a branch such that PRs need, for example, approval by 2 developers as opposed to just 1 but is it possible to have a scenario like this:-

Developer A, Developer B, Developer C, Developer D

If Developer A approves a PR it can be Merged

If Developer B, C, or D approves a PR then it needs approval from another developer.

This would take into account experience of the developers, both as developers in general and in the domain.

Comment: Should just be done with internal agreement, unless you want to write a whole bot that would give and take approvals according to Dev A

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bitbucket Cloud or Server?

Depending on the above, I may have a solution that could work for you

- Sean // Izymes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).